# Django password-reset-confirm not working

Tags: python, django

I want to implement the Django reset password function but it gets stuck when it tries to sent the email. 
Error code: 
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
[error-code-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8NBP.png)

I´ve tried the form with crispy and I´ve tried to let Django do it all alone (without my views) but it´s not working.

urls: [urls-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck2zA.png)

```py
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='web/users/password_reset.html'),
     name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='web/users/password_reset_done.html'),
     name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
         template_name='web/users/password_reset_confirm.html'),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

password-reset-confirm view (just the form):
[password-reset-confirm template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKAD3.png)

```html
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.email }}
    <label for="username" class="control-label">Email</label><i class="bar"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Passwort ändern"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I think the problem is that it´s not passing the uidb64 and the token to the email template.

Comment: urls that you have posted is of main project or any app's url ?

Comment: that are the urls from the app

Comment: Are your urls namespaced maybe (so in your template, you should use `{% url 'account:password_reset_confirm' ... %}`)? the error isn't the missing uid or token, it's about a patter name not found.

Comment: I put a picture from my template in the question. I don´t have an url in it. If I try to use the one from Django and not my own, it´s also not working.

Comment: If I write the url like this: ````path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),````. The same error appiers. So it had nothing to do with my template I think.

Answer (score 3):

I already found the problem. 
I had to write this into the main urls:

```
url(r'^web/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Now it works.
Thank you

Comment: It really worked like charm. However instead of "url", I have used "re_path". Thats all needs to be used with latest versions of Django. I am using 3.0.8